# How to add response header in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I have developed a Web-service based web component, i publishing my service using web service 
and i want to add headers in response so that client can use that header with response result

my web service class ..

```
@WebService()
public class FooService{

@WebMethod()
public String fooWebMethod(String input){
//----some code----
  return resultString;
 }

}
```

My web service client class ..

```
public class WebServInvoker { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
             FooServiceServiceLocator locator = new FooServiceServiceLocator();
             FooService wsClient = locator.getFooServicePort();
             wsClient.fooWebMethod("some string");

       }
}
```

Now i want to send extra information to user in web service response , I have no idea how to do it Please help me

Comment: have a look at handlers http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-testing-for-client-and-server-side/

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler. One way to do it as below

```
@WebService()
@HandlerChain(file = "FooService-HandlerChain.xml")
public class FooService{
      //your code 
}
```

Then your handler file

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <handler-chain>
  <service-name-pattern xmlns:ns1="yournamespacepattern">ns1:FooService</service-name-pattern>
  <handler>
     <handler-name>HandlerClassName</handler-name>
     <handler-class>packagename.HandlerClassName</handler-class>
  </handler>
```

And then your handler class

```
 public class HandlerClassName implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
 {
  public HandlerClassName () {
 }

public Set<QName> getHeaders(){
    return // set of headers;
}


public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context)
{
     //handle message
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Optional.. Let me try to do it this way

Comment: this will add header from client side to read from server side... how it will use to add header from server side and collect it from client side

Comment: @IndraYadav The code is at server side. Isn't it. Annotation @ Webservice annotation is for server side.

Comment: ya this is server side but my que is that how we will add header which can be read from client side...i think getHeader() is used to get the header which comes in webservice request

Comment: See @IndraYadav, with this code server can add "header" in RESPONSE in handleMessage. handleMessage is called before RESPONSE is sent to client. Now once you get the response at client side, you can read it