# How to add response header in JAX-WS?

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a similar method to this:

```
@WebMethod
    public BeanResponse generar(@WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.INOUT, name="auditoria", partName="auditoria") Holder<Param> auditoria, 
                                            @WebParam(name="request") BeanRequest request) throws Exception {
//code
}
```

This web-service show this result:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:generarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://url/">
         <return>
            <codRpta>0</codRpta>
            <msgRpta>RESULT</msgRpta>
            <version>v01</version>
            <!--data of bean-->
         </return>
      </ns2:generarResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want this result

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
        <res1>0</res1>
        <res2>rpta</res2>
        <res3>v01</res3>
   </soap:Header>   
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:generarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://url/">
         <return>
            <codRpta>0</codRpta>
            <msgRpta>RESULT</msgRpta>
            <version>v01</version>
            <!--data of bean-->
         </return>
      </ns2:generarResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I search on internet and I've found tutorials like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219358/how-to-add-response-header-in-jax-ws) but I like to find a solution where I only should modify the bean response or add some anotation to web sevice method.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

I'm guiding me from above tutorial:

I have this in my handleMessage method:

```
Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean)
                   context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

            try {

                Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

                if(context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope() != null)
                    context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getHeader().detachNode();

                Map<String, String> headersResponse = (Map<String, String>) context.get(Constants.CUSTOM_HEADERS_SOAP_RESPONSE);

                SOAPHeader soapHeader = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().addHeader();
                soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://impl.service.paperless.equifax.com.pe/", headersResponse.get(properties.getWrapperResponseHeaderCodRpta()), "ns2"));
                soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://impl.service.paperless.equifax.com.pe/", headersResponse.get(properties.getWrapperResponseHeaderDescRpta()), "ns2"));
                soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://impl.service.paperless.equifax.com.pe/", headersResponse.get(properties.getWrapperResponseHeaderCodConsulta()), "ns2"));

            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return true;
```

But I've get this error in line 16:

```
19:31:01,554 Advertencia [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HANDLER_RAISED_RUNTIME_EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pe.com.equifax.paperless.handlers.ResponseHandler.handleMessage(ResponseHandler.java:82) [classes:]
    at pe.com.equifax.paperless.handlers.ResponseHandler.handleMessage(ResponseHandler.java:1) [classes:]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandleMessage(HandlerChainInvoker.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandlerChain(HandlerChainInvoker.java:253)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeProtocolHandlers(HandlerChainInvoker.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.access$000(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

19:31:01,622 Advertencia [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Interceptor for ****** has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pe.com.equifax.paperless.handlers.ResponseHandler.handleMessage(ResponseHandler.java:82) [classes:]
    at pe.com.equifax.paperless.handlers.ResponseHandler.handleMessage(ResponseHandler.java:1) [classes:]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandleMessage(HandlerChainInvoker.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandlerChain(HandlerChainInvoker.java:253)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeProtocolHandlers(HandlerChainInvoker.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.access$000(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

**EDIT 2**

I don't know if it has some relation with problem, When I deploy web application, I get this error in console (Anyway web application is deployed successly):

```
11:13:57,084 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

11:13:57,092 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just define headers as method @WebParam(mode=OUT,header=true) parameters:

```
@WebMethod
public BeanResponse generar(
    @WebParam(header=true, mode=Mode.INOUT, name="auditoria", partName="auditoria") Holder<Param> auditoria,
    @WebParam(name = "res1", targetNamespace = "http://your_namespace.com/", header = true, mode = Mode.OUT, partName = "res1") Holder<String> res1,
    @WebParam(name = "res2", targetNamespace = "http://your_namespace.com/", header = true, mode = Mode.OUT, partName = "res2") Holder<String> res2,
    @WebParam(name = "res3", targetNamespace = "http://your_namespace.com/", header = true, mode = Mode.OUT, partName = "res3") Holder<String> res3,
    @WebParam(name="request") BeanRequest request) throws Exception {
       //code
    }
```

Also I recommend wrapping your res1 res2 and res3 Strings into complexType wrapper, so you will have only one header with mode=OUT

Comment: When I do this, headers (res1,res2 and res3) show inside labels <soap:Body></soap:Body>. I want that they show inside labels <soap:Header></soap:Header>. Besides, param auditoria shouldn't inside labels <soap:Header></soap:Header>. I thought to remove in the handleMessage method

Comment: are you sure that you have added attributes header = true, mode = Mode.OUT ? What's your CXF version? Is your service generated from WSDL?

Comment: This project looks some strange...It uses spring 4.1.2 and for web services use annotations from JAX-WS...so answering to questions: I'm using attributes header with header = true, mode = Mode.OUT; I don't know what's CXF version and my services is not generated from WSDL. I hope to find a solution.

Comment: @CesarCasasola what's jboss version?

Comment: jboss version is 7.1