# SOAP Custom Response Header - JAX-WS

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

In my JAX-WS web service, I need to customize my SOAP Response Envelope.

At the moment, it is like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <methodResponse xmlns="http://interfaces.webservice.ucmdb.com">
         <methodReturn>202</methodReturn>
      </methodResponse >
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i need it to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
    <code>123</code>
   </soapenv:Header>   
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getCIResponse xmlns="http://interfaces.webservice.ucmdb.com">
         <getCIReturn>202</getCIReturn>
      </getCIResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So, how does one write the `<soapenv:Header>` part in a JAX-WS soap envelope?

Here is my WebMethod implementation (quite simple at the moment):

```
@WebMethod
    public int  operation(@WebParam(name="username", header=false)String id) {
        return 202;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380829/how-to-add-response-header-in-jax-ws

Answer (score 0):

1.) In order to add a header to your SOAP message in JAX-WS you can implement the **SOAPHandler** interface. This will give you access to the SOAPMessage and you can use the **SAAJ** api to add/update the SOAP Header. Keep in mind this handler is bi-directional.

```
public class Handler1 implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        boolean isOutbound = (boolean) context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if(isOutbound){
            SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
            try {
                //Grab the header
                SOAPHeader header = msg.getSOAPHeader();

                //Add whatever QName you need
                header.addHeaderElement(new QName("code"));

                //Save changes.
                msg.saveChanges();

            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //True continue, false halt.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        //Can also add a QName here.
        return null;
    }

}
```

2.) In order to register the Handler you need to add the handler via an xml handler configuration file that should be kept in the classpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler>
            <javaee:handler-class>com.calvinmmiller.service.Handler1</javaee:handler-class>
        </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

3.) This file can be added to the SEI(Service Endpoint Interface) with the annotation below:

```
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
@HandlerChain( file = "handlerFile.xml")
public class Service {
    public int operation(String id){
        return 202;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/soap", new Service());
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I get how it all works, but how can I pass the code value from the service implementation to the handler?

Comment: @user1835591 You can pass the value any way that you would like. If it is inside of the SOAPMessage then use the SAAJ api to access it. [SAAJ](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhg.html)